# Drop down menu -- selects all cases

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, switch-statement

I have a dropdown menu off of my actionbar bar that, upon selecting anything in the menu, the app will open all the activities below the selection in the list. For instance, if in the menu I have Groups, Chats, Friends, Settings for selections, if I were to select Chats, it would open the Chats activity as well as Friends and Settings.

How can I make it so that the app will only open those activities that were selected

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(searchItem);

    return true;
}

// Actionbar items
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            // searchView.OnQueryTextListener();
        case R.id.action_chat: {
            // Starting the tabbed browsing for friends, indie/group chats
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    GroupIndFriendActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        case R.id.action_alarms: {
            Intent alerts = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MyAlerts.class);
            startActivity(alerts);
        }
        case R.id.action_favorite:
            // openSettings();
        case R.id.action_favorite_specials:
            // openSettings();

        case R.id.action_settings: {
            Intent settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    ApplicationSettings.class);
            startActivity(settings);
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `break` statements in your `case` blocks, otherwise execution will fall through to each subsequent `case`.